# Why the date format is changing whenever I switch between periods in YTD. PowerBi

Tags: excel, date, powerbi, format

I have a problem with changing the date format. Whenever I change the periods between the last dates of the months to the last day of January, February and March, the format of the displayed date is different from the format for the other months (April, May... until December) How can I stop PowerBi from doing this?
An example is shown below in the screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]